# TeX/LaTeX vim fold markers options

Tags: folding, filetype-tex

In complex files, especially when writing packages with basic TeX-LaTeX code, the standard definition of [`foldmarker`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldmarker%27), namely `{{{,}}}`, is unfortunate — in effect is quite common to have pieces of code like:

```latex
\pgfkeys{/tikz/t/.add code={}{\ctikzset{text=#1}}}
```

which will trigger the fold closing mechanism. What I am doing is adding on the top of my files the following:

```
% vim: set fdm=marker fmr=%<<<,%>>>:
```

because I think that this will make the folders independent of the settings of other contributors.

Is this a sensible way of doing folding with TeX? Is there any commonly used setting of `foldmarker` for TeX/LaTeX I should be aware of, and use it instead of inventing my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider adopting the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plug-in, which improves support for TeX files in Vim.

Among its features, it supports custom [folding](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/f029f673b259206bb04ca71b97e68d9635b1c4ee/doc/vimtex.txt#L3463), which is able to recognize LaTeX blocks delimited with `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` and use them to define folding.

Furthermore, it recognizes `{{{` and `}}}` but *only within comments*.

See vimtex's documentation under [`:help vimtex-folding`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/f029f673b259206bb04ca71b97e68d9635b1c4ee/doc/vimtex.txt#L3463) for more details, in particular [`:help g:vimtex_fold_types`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/f029f673b259206bb04ca71b97e68d9635b1c4ee/doc/vimtex.txt#L1448) which allows you to customize it.

---

If you decide to use `foldmethod=marker` with the custom `<<<` and `>>>` markers, then instead of `fmr=%<<<,%>>>`, consider using:

```
fmr=<<<,>>>
```

Without the leading `%` comment character.

You're of course going to use those inside comments, so in practice you'll end up using `%<<<` often. However, matching only `<<<` as the marker has advantages, since then you could use additional text at the start of the comment, for example describing the block:

```
% Introduction <<<
```

And the other advantage is that you can precede the marker with a level number, in which case you can for the most part skip the closing markers, if you use matching levels on them:

```
% Introduction 1<<<
...
% Chapter 1: Motivation 1<<<
```

The choice of `<<<` and `>>>` is such that this sequence is very unlikely to happen in the normal body of the text, so forcing them to appear at the start of the comment, with `%<<<`, isn't totally necessary.

(Though note that using `%<<<` still allows using them this way, for example you could have `%<<<` or even `1%<<<` *inside* a comment.)

Comment: Yes, I use `vimtex` --- the automatic folding is great for LaTeX files, but for low-level TeX files like the ones in the `circuitikz` core (the package I maintain) automatic folding is at best not useful, and it is quite slow.

Comment: Note that vimtex can handle `{{{` and `}}}` within comments, so using `%{{{` etc. might be helpful. See also the reference to `g:vimtex_fold_types` which allow you to customize automatic folding. Having said that, perhaps `fdm=marker` works best for you, so since you can easily set that up from a modeline, maybe that's the best choice for you!

Comment: I've read the `vimtex_fold_types` and especially the `markers` option, and hat would be great, matching the pattern only inside comments solves my problem. But problem is that a collaborator that does not use `vimtex` will have the folding completely wrong. So yes, this is the solution, even if I can't use it on some file...

Comment: @Rmano Updated the answer with a further recommendation on using foldmarkers inside comments.

Comment: I think that the syntax for the level number is *after* the marker, like `%>>>1`...