# Change the fold marker characters used to delimit folds

Tags: neovim, folding

So, oftentimes when I create folds, they actually interfere with other parts of my code and begin folding wherever (n)vim finds another group of three `}}}`

A quick example would be:

```tex
% {{{ Custom commands
\newcommand{\textbfit}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

% ... some other code ...

% }}}
```

(N)Vim will not fold this as expected, it'll find the three `}}}` in my code and fold right there, resulting in a fold that looks like this:

```tex
+-- 1 line: Custom commands . . . . . . . . . . . . .

% ... some other code ...

% }}}
```

Is there any way to change the characters that get used as folding markers? For example, something that could be written in the modeline that says that the fold marker character for this file is `|||`. Or, being able to use four, or five `{` characters for a single fold for cases when, in that fold, there will appear three `}}}` just as describeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26261/tex-latex-vim-fold-markers-options?rq=1) now.

Here's a minimal modeline that changes `{{{` `}}}` to `<<<` `>>>`. Change this for your desired symbol and usecase:

```
vim:foldmethod=marker:fmr=<<<,>>>
```

Comment: Yes; you just need to change the foldmarker option

Comment: Type `:set foldmarker?` to see the current value. In this case, this is enough to tell you what needs to be changed. When you need more info, `:h 'foldmarker'`

Comment: I hadn't thought about this before, but now I'm wondering if I can use some non-keyboard character, perhaps a pair of Unicode arrow symbols, as fold characters. I'll have to test it.

Comment: Cool. I set foldmarker to the Unicode symbols for the Greek letters "alpha" and "omega" and things folded right up.